# iOS webview and audio html5 on background

Tags: ios, audio, uiwebview, streaming

I've tried to write my first iOS app. It's a simple UIWebView of a site with HTML5 audio stream (radio). When app is in foreground the audio works perfectly, but, if press the home button or lock the device the audio stop!

If click play on lockscreen or on control center, audio work for about 10 second.

Any solution?

Sorry for bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From http://www.raywenderlich.com/29948/backgrounding-for-ios, the part which explains `Playing Audio in Background`: "If it still doesn’t work for you, it is probably because you’re using the Simulator. Testing it on a device should get it working"

You should try on the Device.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I'll try it on my iDevice, after paying the license. I read that it is impossible to install unsigned app

Comment: Your welcome, please mark my answer as the correct, clicking on the up narrow.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your plist and add the row "Required background modes" with the key "App plays audio or streams audio/video using AirPlay"

Comment: I already tried this solution, but unfortunately it does not work (at least on the iPhone simulator, who knows the "reality") I'm afraid not work with UIWebView

Comment: Background audio is not supported on the Simulator